# Angularfire pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, firebase, angularfire

I am currently building a small personal blog for myself by using Firebase and AngularJS.

Now, I don't want to show all of my posts on the same page. It would soon become slow if I start posting every day. My goal is to have a 'prev' and a 'next' button on the bottom of every blog post for the user to navigate around.

Currently I'm doing it like this, html:

```
<main class="content links-dark" data-ng-controller="postsCtrl">

        <article ng-repeat="(id, post) in posts track by post.$id | orderByPriority | orderBy:'-$id' ">

            <footer>
                <small>{{post.time}}</small> - Less than 1 minute read
            </footer>

            <header class="headline">
                <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
            </header>

            <section>
                <p ng-bind-html="post.body">
                </p>

            </section>

        </article>

        <nav class="articles links-dark">
            <a href="#">next post</a>
        </nav>

    </main>
```

And my js file:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['firebase', 'ngSanitize']);

blogApp.controller('postsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase){

var ref = new Firebase('https://teemublog.firebaseio.com/posts/');

var count = 0, pageSize = 1;
$scope.posts = $firebase(ref);


$scope.nextPage = function loadNextPage() {

    var oldPosts = $scope.posts;
    count += pageSize;

    $scope.posts = ref.startAt().limit(count);

    if (oldPosts) {
        oldPosts.$off();
    }
}

$scope.nextPage();

}]);
```

I grabbed the idea from some other post. I haven't even tried putting nextPage in the anchor yet because this doesn't work at all. Debugger says:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use
>   'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: (id, post) in
>   posts track by post.$id | orderByPriority | orderBy:'-$id', Duplicate
>   key: []

I have already tried fiddling around with the ng-repeat (removing filters etc.), but no success.

My question:
Is this the best way to approach possible pagination when dealing with Firebase, AngularJS and AngularFire? Is there a simpler way?

Thanks a lot,
Tetsii

Comment: Yes. This is about as simple as it gets. It looks like you just have a few typos that might be holding you back. In your ngRepeat change (id, post) to ($id, post). And you probably want to add a value into the .startAt().

Comment: Hey! Thanks for swift reply. Changed to ($id, post) and put a value (1) into .startAt(). Still getting the same error..

Comment: Is posts an array or object? If it is an array you need to change your ngRepeat.

Comment: posts is an object. The ngRepeat works without all the "pagination" stuff. So if I comment out $scope.nextPage and remove the "track by", ng-repeat will list every post on the page succesfully.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use track by on an object. You don't really need it anyway, so I would take it out. Maybe check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/) for a great example of angular pagination.

Comment: Yeah that's an awesome example, thanks! I can work with it, but one of the main issues here is that I need to limit the data coming from Firebase somehow and the code I use now isn't working for some reason..

Comment: You could just keep a list of the ids, and use those to get the page data from firebase. Or each page could have a prevId and nextId? Good luck!